# Confusion on old rest api for edit events for iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am developing an application for I phone in which i need to edit events specially change latitude and longitude of an event. I have a lot search to change lat and long using graph API but i couldn't get any help, and i get solution using old rest API using events.edit method, so my question is that is this best approach to use old rest and also if u suggest me this solution to any other method. So please help me on that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set permission for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the permission with `create_event` which leads user to modify the event details. For more details [link.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).Look for Extended Permissions.

Comment: will this right approach to edit using old rest api, i think which u also mentioning?